# Boolean algebra simplify the expression 3

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

Simplify the expression using the rules in boolean algebra: 
**ae + abc'd + bc'e'**

[Here's a list of the boolean rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdalp.jpg)

I got no solution to this problem. Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: Looks pretty simple to me already ... what is the definition of 'simple' or 'simplest'?

Comment: The correct answer should be ae + bc'e'

Answer (score 1):

$$ae + abc'd + bc'e' \overset{Adjacency}=  ae + abc'de + abc'de' + bc'e' \overset{Absorption \ x \ 2}=ae + bc'e'$$

In other words, the trick is to split the $abc'd$ term into two cases: one where $e$ is true, and one where $e$ is false ... and both of these terms are covered (i.e. get 'absorbed') by the existing terms respectively.

Absorption is B16 by the way.... and I don't see Adjacency on the list, but that's easily derived:

$$abc'd = abc'd1 = abc'd(e + e') = abc'de + abc'de'$$

Comment: Thanks what a cool trick you did there. :)

Comment: @DanielAndersson You are welcome! :)